# What does (N, vector< int >(M, -1)) resemble?

Tags: c++, vector

```
vector< vector< int > > Matrix(N, vector< int >(M, -1));
```

I understand that this is a 2-D vector, N & M is size and -1 is initialized, but what the last "vector < int >" is doing there.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more?  It's unclear to me what you are asking

Comment: What you have is a N * M matrix initialised all elements to -1.

Answer (score 2):

It will allocate `N` elements of `vector<int>` and initialize each of them to `vector< int >(M, -1)`.

`vector< int >(M, -1)` allocates `M` elements of `int` and initialize each of them to `-1`.

Comment: I understand that this is a 2-D vector, N & M is size and -1 is initialized, but what the last "vector < int >" is doing there.Why we didn't use vector thing with N?

Comment: It is constructing a temporary `M`-element vector that serves as template to initialize each elements of the vector `Matrix`.

Answer (score 0):

You're making a 2D matrix, with `N` rows, and `M` columns, where all the cells are initialized to a value of `-1`.